# Tool or technique for examining retina pixels iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, graphics, uikit, core-graphics

I am working on an iOS app that requires very precise drawing and would like to have some way of visually inspecting what, *exactly*, is being drawn to each (physical) pixel on my iOS device screen. This would be similar to the Pixie app dev tool on OS X, but for iOS -- instead of simply blowing up and anti-aliasing the screen, it would show a very clear grid of each and every pixel, and what shades/colors are being drawn to those pixels.

Does anyone know of such a tool or technique?

Here's a screenshot from Pixie on OS X on my Retina MacBook that shows the kind of output I'm looking for. You can clearly see, for example, that the designers specified 1 point (which spans two retina pixels) for the "minus" sign in the yellow minimize icon.

[image]

Comment: There isn't going to be anything on device that will allow this.  My only advice would be to simply take screenshots, import them on your Mac, and use Pixie.  That's about a smooth a workflow as you could get.

Comment: You can take screenshots directly from Xcode and they will be saved on your Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Quartz to do your drawing to a UIView you can draw on pixel boundaries and not on point boundaries by using `CGContextScaleCTM`.  Here is a rough outline of what you would do to do this with a screen shot of your app.  You could also have the user take a screen shot of a different app and then import it into yours.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIView* rootView = <GET_YOUR_ROOT_VIEW>;

    //You will probably want to change rect so you don't get distortion 
    //This assumes that this view is the same size as the screen
    [rootView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,rect.size.width*8, rect.size.height*8, afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    CGContextRef cxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Assumes this is @2x retina.  You should check the contentScale to be sure
    //and change accordingly
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 0.5, 0.5);

    //Since we made the screen shot be 8x bigger the pixels
    //on an @2x device are in increments of 4
    for (int x = 0; x < rect.size.width*8; x+=4)
    {
        //Draw a line at x to ctx
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < rect.size.height*8; y+=4)
    {
        //Draw a line at y to ctx
    }

}
```

I am sorry that I don't have time to actually write and test this code myself, so there is probably a few little issues with it.  But this should get you going in the right direction.

Also, since you are blowing up the image you actually don't need to change the scale with CGContextScaleCTM, you just need to draw your lines at the right intervals.